# Why not use the EventFiringWebDriver object directly instead of wrapping WebDriver object and then use it?

Tags: selenium, webdriver

I am learning WebDriver listeners. To listen and act accordingly, we have to first create an instance of WebDriver and pass it to the instance of EventFiringWebDriver.

So the code will be like

```
WebDriver wdriver = new FirefoxDriver();
EventFiringWebDriver driver = new EventFiringWebDriver(wdriver);
```

I've come to know that the class EventFiringWebDriver is a wrapper of WebDriver and it added functionality to listen to events and invoke the overridden methods of the WebDriverEventListener.

So the code now will be like

```
OverrideClass oc = new OverrideClass();
driver.register(oc);
```

From now onwards, we code like we used to do using FirefoxDriver.
for example, to open a url

```
driver.get("https://www.facebook.com");
```

to find an element

```
driver.findElement(By.id("email"));
```

and so on.

So I can deduct that both FirefoxDriver and EventFiringWebDriver are having same methods but implemented differently.

For example, take findElement.
In FirefoxDriver, it is implemented as "find the element and return the object of type WebElement".

In EventFiringWebDriver, it is implemented as "find the element. if it is not found, invoke the overridden method '**onException**'. If it is found, return the object of type WebElement".

Please correct me if I am wrong.

Now my doubt is if we are going to use methods in EventFiringWebDriver, why not just create an instance of it and use it's methods like

```
EventFiringWebDriver driver = new EventFiringWebDriver();
driver.get("https://www.facebook.com");
driver.findElement(By.id("email"));
```

I am not proposing this in any way. I just want to know the logic behind wrapping the WebDriver object first and then using the EventFiringWebDriver object.

I know that

```
EventFiringWebDriver driver = new EventFiringWebDriver();
```

is not possible as there is no such constructor.

I just want to know the logic of wrapping the WebDriver object first and then to do the scripting using the EventFiringWebDriver object.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Great question, I am also working on this same subject and would like to share few points from my side. Hope my point gets you direct answer or some clue to debug further.

Points:

```
EventFiringWebDriver driver = new EventFiringWebDriver();
driver.get("https://www.facebook.com");
driver.findElement(By.id("email"));
```

As you said you cannot use this way because it does not have any implementation or constructor

The implementations of Webdriver methods in EventFiringWebDriver still uses the Wrapper object of ChromeDriver or Firefox  to perform findelements or getcurrenturl etc. Different in this EventFiringWebDriver is it uses the Implementation class of AbstractWebDriverListner logs before and after performing actions.

Example:

```
  @Override
  public void get(String url) {
    dispatcher.beforeNavigateTo(url, driver); --- This is the logging part
    driver.get(url); --- Uses the driver object from Webdriver obj = new ChromeDriver();
    dispatcher.afterNavigateTo(url, driver); -- This is the logging part
  }
```